# Is there official JavaScript and CSS icons?

Tags: javascript, css, html, icons

I already have found HTML5, PHP icons to use in project (on website). The HTML5 icon is on W3C site and PHP icon is on php.net site. But how about JS, CSS icons? Because I have found this JavaScript icon: [image], but I don't know: can I use it or not? And one more question: is there CSS/JS/HTML5 file icon? I have found only PHP file icon.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png

Comment: OK, it's HTML5 icon... (I already have found it) But others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably no "official" icon, because there is no body officially "governing" JavaScript. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606212/why-is-there-no-official-javascript-reference) related Stack Overflow question about the "official" manual on JavaScript. Instead, JavaScript is a derivative of ECMAScript. Glancing over the [official ECMAScript website](http://www.ecmascript.org/) I don't see any official logo's or icons for ECMAScript either, not even in the specification documents (for version 3 nor for version 5).

Interestingly, the [Wikipedia article on JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) shows this logo, which I'd personally never seen before:

[image]

this is a semi official icon as said in [here](http://www.2ality.com/2011/10/logo-js.html).

In response to your second question: I guess if I must choose then I would go for any icon in my existing house style with these two features:
Capitals "JS"
Indication that the icon's about code

To add to this, see there's this related icon:
 JScript: Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript

### **update**

Wikipedia has removed the icon from their article on JS, however, this is still the top result in google search and I have found no other JS icon

Comment: OK. And how about CSS icon?

Comment: i've found an article of microsoft saying the is an official logo, but no luck on finding what is it... 10 more minutes

Comment: i've got this - http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-YTiH-WSka84/UQNlvIwQZsI/AAAAAAAAW9E/7FzoNxea6X4/s200/css3-logo.png
but couldn't find out if it's official... sorry

Comment: Note: Wikipedia article on JavaScript is fixed and this dubious logo is gone

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny still this is the top result in google, and is the best i could find