# Where can I find official coding definitions for JavaScript similar to Python's PEPs?

Tags: javascript, python

I need an official place where I can quote JavaScript coding conventions similar to what Python have as [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/)s, for instance that JavaScript files should [end with an empty new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline).

The reason why I need to quote things like this is because I am putting together a document of rules/advises that should be followed for a specific project I manage. Too many bugs with our build and whatnot could be avoided and time not wasted if it were for this document to exist already. I believe many of us here feel this pain.

Comment: [Mozilla have great extensive info on bets coding practices for JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style), and of course you can refer to the [official spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606212/why-is-there-no-official-javascript-reference

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606212/why-is-there-no-official-javascript-reference

Comment: @samiles this definitely works for me, thanks.